# Distribution of values of quadratic polynomials over a finite field

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $S$ denote the set of squares in the finite field ${\mathbb F}_p$. Now
let $f(x) \in {\mathbb F}_p[x]$ denote a degree $2$ polynomial, which is not a 
square of a linear polynomial. If we consider the function
$f: {\mathbb F}_p \longrightarrow {\mathbb F}_p$, then
it  seems plausible that the cardinality of the set 
$\text{image}(f) \cap S$ should be approximately $p/4$,  i.e., $f$ should hit
about   half the squares. I have tested this numerically on many examples.

I would be grateful if anyone were to know a reference for such a
result, especially if the error term is identified concretely.  Since the
issue is asymptotic, one may assume $p$ to be sufficiently large.

Answer (score 5):

Up to linear change of variable we have either $f(x)=x^2+b$ or $f(x)=gx^2+b$ for some $g\notin S$, $b\ne 0$. In the first case equation $f(x)=y^2$ reduces to $b=y^2-x^2=(y-x)(y+x)$, this has exactly $(p-1)$ solutions, almost all pairs $(x^2,y^2)$ are counted four times for $(\pm x,\pm y)$. In the second case we get a condition $y^2-b\notin S$. But we know already how often $y^2-b\in S$, so it is easy to calculate.